# How to configure datatable so that it will order(desc) the records based on the created_date?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, sorting, date, datatable

i am using `datatable` in my `rails` App to the User `index` page. my first `column` in the `index` page is `created_at`. the `data` in this `column` looks like `Mon, 17-Oct-16`. I want to make this column should be sorted according to this date format in `desc` `order`. how can i do that?
this is what i tried. but it did not worked.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var index = $('#reg_req_data_table').dataTable({
      "order": [[ 1, "desc" ]],
       'aoColumnDefs': [{
       'bSortable': false      
    }],
    "bLengthChange": false,
    "sDom": '<"top"pfl>rt<"bottom"i><"clear">'
      });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I would use Bates' railscast and follow his approach creating a separate class to handle the logic.  It follows Rails conventions and allows you to handle most of the manipulation in ruby such as sorting.

Comment: If you want a full writeup, I'll show you how to do this the "rails" way.  Just let me know if you haven't solved it yet.

Comment: no its not solved. please help me in rails way

Answer (score 0):

This answer will show you how to follow Rails conventions and handle sorting in a ruby class before dishing back out as json to DataTables.  Also, if you're handling more than hundreds of records it is highly recommended you use server-side processing which is much faster instead of client-side processing (this example will show server-side):

Your user#index action should be:

```
def index
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json { render json: UsersDatatable.new(view_context) }
  end
end
```

You should create a subfolder in your app folder named datatables and then add this .rb file to it:

```
#app/datatables/users_datatable.rb   Notice it's called users_datatable! Rails will infer the proper class lookup path because of this.
class UsersDatatable
  delegate :params, :h, :link_to, to: :@view

  def initialize(view)
    @view = view
  end

  def as_json(options = {})
    {
      sEcho: params[:sEcho].to_i,
      iTotalRecords: User.count,
      iTotalDisplayRecords: users.total_entries,
      aaData: data
    }
  end

private

  def data
    users.map do |user|
      [
        user.created_at.strftime("%d-%b-%y")
      ]
    end
  end

  def users
    @users ||= fetch_users
  end

  def fetch_users
    users = User.all.order("created_at DESC")
    users = users.page(page).per_page(per_page)
    if params[:search].present? && params[:search]["value"].present?
      users = users.where("email like :search", search: "#{params[:search]["value"]}%")
    users
  end

  def page
    params[:start].to_i/per_page + 1
  end

  def per_page
    params[:length].to_i > 0 ? params[:length].to_i : 10
  end

  def sort_column
    columns = %w[created_at ]
    columns[params[:order]["0"]["column"].to_i]
  end

  def sort_direction
    params[:order]["0"]["dir"] == "desc" ? "desc" : "asc"
  end
end
```

Now your corresponding users view `index.html.erb` should be:

```
<div class='table-responsive'>
  <table id='reg_req_data_table' data-source="<%= users_path(params.merge!(format: :json).deep_symbolize_keys)%>">
  <thead>
    <tr>
       <th>Created On:</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#reg_req_data_table').DataTable({
       "serverSide": true,
       "ajax": {url: '<%= users_path(params.merge!(format: :json).deep_symbolize_keys)%>', type: "POST"},
       "processing": true
    }),
  });
</script>
```

Notice how there is nothing in the table body tags.  Serverside processing sets datatables accept that info via json which is what we send in the UsersDatatable class.